# Django Rest Framework nested objects create with request.user

Tags: django, model, django-rest-framework, authorization

I want my visitors to have function for creating and get list of Proposals.

User sends all of the data except the author of Proposal (because the auth is user himself), so I'm trying to extend request.data with request.user like this:

```
# proposals/views.py
class ProposalsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Proposal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProposalSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data={
            **request.data,
            "author": request.user.id,
          })
          serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
          self.perform_create(serializer)
          headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Although, I want to GET the proposals list with serialized author (user), so my serializer looks like:

```
# proposals/serializers.py
class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
         model = SeekerProposal
         fields = ('text', 'author')
```

**The problem** is that I GET users list correctly (serialized to dict), but I can't POST (create new) Proposal, because it wants to "author" be a dict (it happens because I'm using nested serializer author = UserSerializer()).

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to let view be ListCreateAPIView and author = UserSerializer() while GET list with serialized data and create proposal by request.user.id?
2. Maybe there is another way to add authorized user to Proposal author field?

Also, this is my model:

```
# proposals/models.py
class Proposal(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user),
    )
```

**Answer**

User [@zaidfazil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7256228/zaidfazil) helped me with solution.
I needed to add just one more additional field to my serializer for author details to be shown serialized:

```
# proposals/serializers.py
class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_details = UserSerializer(source='author', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SeekerProposal
        # author will be user id, and author_details will be serialized dict
        fields = ('text', 'author', 'author_details')
```

Because `author` is still just user id and `author_details` is `read_only=True` I will get all the data for author in `GET` request and can create new proposal by `author=request.user.id`.

One moment:

I didn't use `blank=True` on `author` field, because I must be sure that this field is not empty. So my view looks the same as I wrote it above (`post` on `ProposalsList`).

Again, thanks a lot to [@zaidfazil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7256228/zaidfazil)! If I wrote something wrong please write me, I'm kind of nooby on stackoverflow.

Comment: Some kind of answer was creating new serializer called ProposalNestedSerializer that inherits my ProposalSerializer and extends author = UserSerializer(), while removing it from ProposalSerializer. So now, I'm using ProposalNestedSerializer for GET (and getting serialized author in response) and using ProposalSerializer with POST (and can create Proposals with just request.user.id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual way would be defining your `author` field as `blank=True` in your models and passing the user when saving the serializer,

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user), blank=True)
```

serializers.py,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', .....)

class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_details = UserSerializer(source='author', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SeekerProposal
        fields = ('text', 'author', 'author_details')
```

Then, in your view,

```
class ProposalsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = SeekerProposal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SeekerProposalSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks!
But theres still problems:
Firstly, on GET i need a list of proposals with serialized author and on POST creating proposal with author=request.user.id (but I can't, because if I use author = UserSerializer() in ProposalSerializer it ask for object while creating)
Secondly, I don't want to make author blank=True, because it's a bit danger (I need auth for lots of situations)

Comment: making author `blank=True` would not cause any effect, cuz assigning user will only be handled from behind the scenes. Otherwise, it'd lose the security itself, also `user` field is still mandatory. For your question about the author details, you could add a `read_only` fields in the GET request, to view the details of the existing author info. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: You gave me way to solve this problem! I'll describe it in my question. But two things: I need to be sure that author is not blank, so I really don't want to user `blank=True` and I didn't, also can you add 'author_details' to tuple in your answer for anyone else to be not confused why they getting error)